# GWT: Class cast exception while dispatching incoming RPC call

Tags: java, gwt, rpc

I am developing a web application and get this error but can't make sense of it (I've looked at similar questions but the answers there don't seem to apply to my problem)
Can anyone make sense of this? 
Please help me.

```
 [WARN] Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError cannot be cast to java.lang.Exception
at net.sf.gilead.gwt.PersistentRemoteService.processCall(PersistentRemoteService.java:177)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:373)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:755)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:686)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1494)
at org.realityforge.gwt.cache_filter.GWTGzipFilter.doFilter(GWTGzipFilter.java:57)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
at ... (more eclipse.jetty...)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[ERROR] 500 - POST /webproj/login (127.0.0.1) 57 bytes
   Request headers
  Host: (...)
  User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0
  Accept: */*
  Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
  Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
  Content-Type: text/x-gwt-rpc; charset=utf-8
  (leaving some stuff out)
  Connection: keep-alive
   Response headers
  Content-Type: text/plain
```

Comment: Looks like it might be a bug in the gilead project - but the real issue is that NoClassDefFoundError, some class is missing from your server.

Comment: @ColinAlworth Is there a way to check which class is missing?

Comment: Well, ideally you'd first fix the class cast issue... but if you can debug it, tell your IDE to pause on any NoClassDefFoundError thrown? Or pause on the ClassCastException, and inspect what the rest of the NoClassDefFoundError says in its message?